# In javascript, why is this showing when I console.log but not when I return

Tags: javascript, return, console.log

Fairly new to Javascript, so try not to attack too much :). Here's the challenge I'm trying to solve. When I `console.log` it, it returns what I'm looking for, but when I replace `console.log` with return, it doesn't return anything. Can someone help clarify? Thank you.

My challenge is:

> Write a function, `callTimes`, that returns a new function. The new function should return the number of times it’s been called.

```js
function callTimes() {
  let count = 0;
  return function inner(){
    count++;
    console.log(count)
  }
  return inner
}

let myNewFunc1 = callTimes();
let myNewFunc2 = callTimes();
myNewFunc1(); // => 1
myNewFunc1(); // => 2
myNewFunc2(); // => 1
myNewFunc2(); // => 2
```

If I do the same thing but replace `console.log` with `return`, it doesn't return anything. Trying to figure out why:

```js
function callTimes() {
  let count = 0;
  return function inner(){
    count++;
    return count
  }
  return inner
}

let myNewFunc1 = callTimes();
let myNewFunc2 = callTimes();
myNewFunc1(); // => 1
myNewFunc1(); // => 2
myNewFunc2(); // => 1
myNewFunc2(); // => 2
//Output should be the same as above... 
//but nothing logged
```

Comment: Where and how are you trying this? [Works for me with a `return count` instead of `console.log(count)`](https://jsbin.com/pazasevovo/1/edit?js,console)

Comment: I was trying it in repl.it. Yeah, I'm a little dumbfounded. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

In your second example, the numbers are *returned* correctly, but they didn't show up in the console.

That's because `return` **does not** log anything. `return` is the part of the language, not a debugger tool.

When you `return` something, that value goes back to the caller and allow it to perform more operations with the value, e.g. doing math, storing to variable, passing to another functions, calling (like how you did in case of the function returned from `callTimes()`)...

So, to see those values in the console, log them after they're returned:

```js
function callTimes() {
  let count = 0;
  return function inner(){
    count++;
    return count //<--Return instead of logging
  }
  return inner
}

let myNewFunc1 = callTimes();
let myNewFunc2 = callTimes();
//Log the returned values
console.log(myNewFunc1()); // => 1
console.log(myNewFunc1()); // => 2
console.log(myNewFunc2()); // => 1
console.log(myNewFunc2()); // => 2
```

Comment: thanks. I did that, and it worked, but i was confused as to why it wasn't showing up when I just used return. i guess I got the answer, is that it returns it, but it doesn't log it. thanks again

Comment: @Scottburs I'm glad that I could help :D Yes, when you return a value in JS, you return it to do other operations with it: then finally display it somehow (or not). So, `return` does nothing but *returns* it (no logging done). Btw, you can accept an answer if it helped using  the grey tick mark next to it...